# Where to look to get Magento Quality Patches as .patch or .txt file?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, patches

I am having issue of cron job resulting in error due to process a large number of items. I've checked logs but it fails without any log in cron_schedule table.

After searching for some time I found a patch available MQP [MDVA-28409](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050142171-MDVA-28409-Magento-patch-Magento-web-server-crashing-Out-of-memory) which seems to be related to issue I am facing. But it is not applicable in my magento instance M2.4.2 EE using MQP tool. Still I want to check with applying this patch but I am not able to find it anywhere.

Can anyone please help me with where to find .txt or .patch file of this patch.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@rahul MDVA-28409 this patch is available for Magento2.3.4OS version

You can find source code in below path

> vendor/magento/quality-patches/patches/os/MDVA-28409_2.3.4.patch

Still if you are not able find that I am attaching here.

> https://hastebin.com/xagapufuna.diff

Comment: Thanks @Rutvee.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this section from that page, where detail information given.

**Apply the patch**

For instructions on how to apply an MQP patch, use the following links depending on your Magento product:

```
a. Magento Commerce: DevDocs Apply patches using Magento Quality Patches Tool .
b. Magento Commerce Cloud: DevDocs Upgrades and Patches > Apply patches .
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually my question is different. Anyway I got to know that the issue this patch resolves is already there in the M2.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

All quality patches can be found in the [respective GitHub repository](https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/tree/master/patches/).